# Mass-Spring-Dashpot System: Confusion Over Damping Type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

"Suppose we have a mass-spring-dashpot system with $m=10$, $c=9$, and $k=2$, with $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 5.$ Find how far to the right this mass moves before starting back towards the origin."

*Note: $c$ is the resistance of the medium (dashpot), $k$ is the spring constant.

**My Work:**

I think I'm misunderstanding this concept, so I'll outline my thought process. The test to determine whether this system is over, under, or critically damped is:

$c^2 > 4km \to$ overdamped

$c^2 = 4km \to$ critically damped

$c^2 < 4km \to$ underdamped

In this case, $c^2 = 9^2 = 81, 4km = 4\cdot2\cdot10 = 80.$ Therefore, $c^2 > 4km $ and the system should be overdamped, meaning there is no oscillation and the mass will never move back towards the origin. However, according to my textbook, the answer is *actually* 4.1, meaning that my logic is wrong here, and the system must be underdamped. Where did I go wrong to arrive at my conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your logic is that an overdamped system may actually cross the origin. In fact, you can show that such a system may cross the origin at most once.

Comment: To my understanding, an overdamped system with this description will simply have a mass move in one direction, then stop. Are you saying that's not actually what will happen?

Comment: A lot of the time that is what will happen, but an overdamped system is *defined* by $c^2 > 4km$, not by not crossing the origin. Try solving the system explicitly and graphing it in your calculator.